# Não consigo abrir o link de minha grid view

Tags: c#, asp.net

fiz o seguinte código

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="ID_PTD" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" EmptyDataText="There are no data records to display.">
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="CAMINHO" HeaderText="CAMINHO" SortExpression="CAMINHO" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="NOME" HeaderText="NOME" SortExpression="NOME" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="PROFESSOR" HeaderText="PROFESSOR" SortExpression="PROFESSOR" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="ETEC" HeaderText="ETEC" SortExpression="ETEC" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="DATA" HeaderText="DATA" SortExpression="DATA" />
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Documentos">
            <EditItemTemplate>
                        <a ID="hpCaminho" class="materialize-textarea"  href ='<%# Bind("CAMINHO") %>' runat="server">Abrir</a>
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <a ID="hpCaminho" class="materialize-textarea"  href ='<%# Bind("CAMINHO") %>' runat="server">Abrir</a>
                    </ItemTemplate>  
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
```

ele executa sem erros no meu visual studio porem, ao clicar no link da grid view nada acontece

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

podemos ver que no canto inferior esquerdo ele mostra o caminho, mas quando clico em abrir ele não abre, por que ele não abre e como posso resolver isto

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você não pode abrir um arquivo local na máquina do usuário através de um link, por razões de segurança isso é bloqueado na maioria dos browsers

Se você abrir o console, certamente verá um erro  semelhante a `"Not allowed to load local resource"`

O que você pode fazer é mapear esse diretório no seu servidor e fornecer um caminho relativo ou, por exemplo, criar um método que vai ler esse arquivo no caminho físico do servidor e devolver para o usuário o stream para download.

Comment: se fosse o caso de meu arquivo estar no servidor, ele conseguirá abrir?

Comment: acabei de testar com um caminho de um arquivo .pdf online e funcionou, quando eu passar meu projeto to servidor ocorrera tudo bem, obg pela ajuda